# Xbox 360 Bing hijacking Dashboard

Tags: xbox-360

Whenever I boot up my console, end a game, or simply tap guide button and Y, the Bing page shows up instead of my Dashboard. My LB works fine and the hijacking is annoying.

I've tried: 1. delete and re-download my profile; 2. clear cache; 3. update rollback; 4. install offline update.

As long as I sign in Xbox Live, Bing hijacks my Dashboard. If I skip sign-in or sign in with no internet, no Bing, no pain.

Only found one post about 2 months ago: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/927749-xbox-360/72011688

Anyone knows how to fix this? I've wasted way more time than expected. Chat with xbox support did provide some plan like rollback and offline update, but didn't work.

Comment: Have the same problem. Does your settings tab also show two kinect boxes?

Comment: yes, didn't realize that until you mentioned it. The down-left corner should be "Account", but when signed-in it's another "Kinect". Disconnect from XLive and it becomes "Account" again.

Comment: the 2 "Kinect" issue is gone on my console, but Bing home is still there. Same to yours?

Answer (score -3):

This is probably a problem on microsofts end. I've heard that recently there's been problems with the servers.

Comment: Welcome on Arqade ! Consider reading the [Tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately, you *probably* don't really answer the question, unless you have a trustable source.